# connectionreseterror: (errno 104) connection reset by peer

Tags: python, django, server, connection, peer

I am working on a Django web project. One moment before all was good but suddenly django localhost server kept itself reloading and not stopping auto-reloading the pages. First I got the following error: **connectionreseterror: (errno 104) connection reset by peer**
And the server just kept reloading itself over and over again. What could be the cause for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOlved**.
I was using JQuery autocomplete to search data from backend and wanted to implement onclick functionality that redirects the user to that specific item page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'ajax-search' %}",
            select: function (event, ui) {
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
            }
        })
        window.location.href = ''
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
                <label for="search"></label><input type="text" oninput="" style="height: 36px" class="searchTerm"
                                                   placeholder="What are you looking for?" name="searchtext"
                                                   id="search"><input type="hidden" id="project-id">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
```

and Issue was in line :

```js
window.location.href = ''
```

I removed that line of code and now it's all good :)

Answer (score -1):

What is your Django package version?

There is exception in django project like yours
https://github.com/django/django/commit/934acf1126995f6e6ccba5947ec8f7561633c27f

Try to update django to newest version

```
pip install --update django
```

Answer (score -1):

We all install kserve, knative, istio, and cert-manager while integrating the system  istio-system to the local or kserve we follow the mtls enabled in a strict mode.
Example:

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Peer Authentication
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: user1
spec:
  mtls:
    mode:  STRICT
```

we have to disable this configuration. It's better to avoiding applying it. When don't use the DNS